# AUC - Logistic Regression versus LDA, and Naive Bayes

Tags: logistic, modeling, roc, naive-bayes, auc

everyone!

I am a newbie on machine learning, and I am now interested on classification modeling.

I used logistic regression, linear discriminant analysis (LDA), and naive Bayes on my notebook [DataCamp Certification - Travel Insurance](https://www.kaggle.com/code/gregoryoliveira/datacamp-certification-travel-insurance) as a tool to exploratory data analysis. A thing that caught my attention is the difference between AUC of the three models, more specific between logistic regression and the other tow techniques. I use the [Yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org) to calculate this measure.

Well, I am trying to apply this same strategy on [Titanic - Machine Learning from Disaster](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic). When I model on [my notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/gregoryoliveira/titanic-ml-from-disaster) the data with logistic regression, I was surprised by a AUC very low (0.1464) despite my score of 0.7584 on the competition.

It is important to say that some terms on the first notebook show a low p.value. Differently, the second notebook, all terms show p.value < 0.05.

So, I would like to understand this situation because it is worries me a lot!

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Please note that values of AUC-ROC below 0.50 suggest that the label during evaluation are likely inverted.

Comment: An AUC less than 0.5 means the model could do better by just switching the predicted labels.  Are you sure there is no bug in your code which may code positive responses as 0 and negative responses as 1? If your outcome is a factor, this can happen easily.

Comment: @Gregory Oliveira Your links are broken.

Comment: @frank I changed them. I try to send you directly to the cells that I want.

Comment: I'll inspect again, but I had tried to look at this issue of changing labels before. If successful, I'll let you know here. Thank you!

Comment: The concordance probabilty (aka $c$-index and AUROC) is not sensitive enough for comparing two models as it does not sufficiently reward extreme predictions that are correct.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/addvalue) for sensitive measures.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I’m getting a “page not found” error. Is there a typo in the link URL?

Comment: You mean p-values for the confidence of factors? I can't say for sure, because I don't see the code here (yes please, provide all of the materials in the question for futher convinience), but when default hypothesis for coefficients of linear regression (or logistic) is that coeffs. are **confident**, the less p-value the better.

Comment: @Dave links are working here... :-/ Try to go with my Kaggle profile... https://www.kaggle.com/gregoryoliveira

Comment: @taciturno I just mention the p.value because this maybe a important information about the influence on AUC.

Comment: @usεr11852 I inspect the Titanic notebook and the factors are correct. :-/

Comment: @GregoryOliveira that's no need to put your whole notebooks or links on notebooks -- it's just not convinient and makes problem too broad to answer. Please, make a new question, specify a problem, put few line of code right there

Comment: You did a good job (+1) just the function used had a bit of an issue. I comment this further in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unintended behaviour by `yardstick::roc_auc`; if we used another library to compute AUC-ROC, e.g. `MLmetrics::AUC(y_true=data_select_pred$Survived, y_pred=data_select_pred$ProbSurvived)`, we would get an AUC-ROC value of ~0.8536 that matches 1 minus the value you currently get. In general, AUC-ROC values significantly below 0.5 are very often related to coding error/label inversion. The CV.SE thread on: [Can AUC-ROC be between 0-0.5?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266387/can-auc-roc-be-between-0-0-5) explores this further.

Please consider opening an issue about this in [`yardstick` git repo](https://github.com/tidymodels/yardstick/). There is a [similar issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/yardstick/issues/234) mentioned in September 2021 which I suspect affects you too.

Comment: I will document the situation and report to them! Thanks for your support. :-)

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help!